# Solarium return Solr HTTP error : OK (404)

Tags: solr

I use Solarium to access Solr with Symfony. It works without problem on my computer and dev computer but not on prod server.

On the prod server, Sorl is running with the same configuration, same port, same logins.

Do you have any idea of what can be the problem?

Here is the error

```
Solr HTTP error: OK (404)
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Since the error message is a 404, the http server you're contacting is telling you that there isn't any resources as the given URL. If it's actually the correct server (i.e. Solr), usually either Solr isn't running properly, you're using the wrong collection name or the collection doesn't exist. What happens if you open the URL you've configured directly in your browser? Also, remember that things like `#` in the URL are local anchors and not something that should be included in the configured URL.

Comment: When I access the url directly by browser, I have the admin solr panel and the collections with the data. If access by the url that is generate by Symfony, I have a json with the data from the query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There was a wrong proxy installed on the windows server.